# query on runtime polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual void showbase() {
        // ----------
    }
};

class base1 {
public:
    virtual void showbase1() {
        // -------
    }
};

class derived : public base, public base1
{
    void showbase() {
        // ----  
    }

    void showbase1() {
        // -------
    }
};

int main()
{
    base* p = new derived();
    p->showbase1();

    base1* p1 = new derived();
    p1->showbase();
}
```

As per my understanding about virtual function is that compiler deals it with run time (vtable mechanism), then why I am getting compile time error.

Comment: error C2039: 'showbase1()' : is not a member of 'base' and error C2039: 'showbase()' : is not a member of 'base1', i understood the problem but my query why compiler is not deals with run time polymorphism.

Comment: See updated answer re: runtime polymorphism and multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per my understanding about virtual function is that compiler deals it with run time (vtable mechanism), then why I am getting compile time error.

"Deals with it" is pretty vague and vtables are not magic; In C++ virtual dispatch allows for the actual function called to be one that overrides the statically declared virtual function. That means that the function which is being overridden must be known at compile time.

The vtable does not contain information that would be necessary to look up functions at run-time. Instead, it's basically just a list of pointers to overriding functions. The base provides a complete list of its virtual functions and so, given a particular base type, the compiler knows at compile-time where to go in the vtable for that base for a particular function override; The compiler can generate code that goes directly to that spot in the vtable, gets the pointer, and calls the overriding function.

Then, at run-time, when the actual object of derived type is created, the derived object's constructor fills in the base's vtable, so that anything checking the vtable will get pointers to the derived type's functions.

So the problem with your code is that the function you're calling, `showbase()`, is not on the list of virtual functions for the type the compiler knows you're accessing, `base1`; The compiler can't know where in `base1's` vtable to get a pointer for a function override named `showbase()`, because there is no such entry in `base1`'s vtable.

Answer (score 2):

To simulate a compiler, consider what a compiler sees:

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual void showbase() {
        // ----------
    }
};

base* p = /*blah blah*/;
p->showbase1();
```

Yes, `base` is a polymorphic class.  And `p` is indeed a pointer-to`base`.  But since `p` points just to  a `base`, and importantly *not* to a `base1` (where `showbase1` lives) the compiler interprets the above code like this.  Obviously, I'm paraphrasing:

> ```
> Here is a class named `base` with a single virtual method called `showbase`.  
> Here is a pointer to a `base` object.  Call the method named `showbase1`
> ```

And the compiler complains:

> Um, excuse me buddy, but `base` doesn't have a method called
>   `showbase1`.

---

You asked:

> [My] understanding about virtual function is that compiler deals with
>   it at run time.  Why I am getting compile time error?

Because the code you've written is nonsense.  Here basically is how polymorphism works.

1. You define a base class with virtual methods.
2. You define a derived class that overrides those virtual methods.
3. The compiler creates a vtable which maps the names of the methods in the base class to the implementation in the derived class.
4. When you call a method in the base class through a pointer (or ref) to the base class, the derived class' implementation is called.

But what you are trying to do is:

1. Define a base class with virtual methods.
2. Define a derived class which overrides those virtual methods.
3. Call a function in a completely different class.

Answer (score 1):

Your base class(es) only know about their own member functions, so you can't use it this way.  You could do this instead:

```
base* p = new derived();
p->showbase();

base1* p1 = new derived();
p1->showbase1();
```

To answer your question about runtime polymorphism, it is dealing with runtime polymorphism (late binding) via the vtable, as you say.  But with multiple inheritance, there is essentially a vtable for for each base class.  You can't access one base class' vtable via a pointer to the other base class.

Answer (score 1):

A base class pointer to a derived class can only access the member functions defined in the base class. It is illegal to try and access other functions defined in the derived class through it. In your case `base` class does not define `showbase1` and therefore this is illegal

```
base* p = new derived();
p->showbase1(); //illegal
```

However, you can do this:

```
p->showbase(); // legal because showbase is a member function of base
```

Similarly you can't access `showbase1` using a `base` class pointer

```
base1* p1 = new derived();
p1->showbase();  //illegal
p1->showbase1(); //legal
```

Comment: that i know but my query is in case of virtual function compiler depends upon vtable since p has content of derived class object and derived vtable has entry of showbase1, then why i am getting compiletime error, what u r pointing i also understood but want to understand how compiler works for compilation of virtual function.

Comment: You misunderstand the concept. It is decided at runtime whether to call the base class's or the derived class's version of a virtual function. The base class, and hence the base class pointer has no knowledge of any functions defined outside it. Therefore, trying to access any other function except the base class's member function is a compile time error.

Comment: If the derived class provides a specialization of the virtual function, then the derived class's version is called at runtime otherwise the base class's version will be called.

Answer (score 0):

**p**'*static type* s type is **base** and hence you can only call with it functions that have been definied into **base** even if at the end, it will be the functions from **derived** which will be called because p's dynamic type is **derived**

Same thing happens for p1.

Maybe you meant `p->showbase();` and `p1->showbase1();`